# Delphi - dbGo/Oracle method GetFieldNames returns no data

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado

Delphi Rio - I am just starting to learn ADO, specifically the dbGo components, connected to a local Oracle RDBMS (Oracle 12.2 64 bit).  I am able to connect, issue simple queries, etc.  I found the method TADOConnection.GetFieldNames, and I am experimenting with it.  I am not able to get it to work.  Here is my code...

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
S1 : TStringList;

begin
 S1 := TStringList.Create;
 ADO1.Connected := True;
 ADO1.GetFieldNames('EGR.ACCOUNTS', S1);
 //ADO1.GetTableNames(S1, False);
 ShowMessage(IntToStr(S1.Count));
 S1.Free;
end;
```

I have tried with and without the Schema name, yet S1.Count always returns 0.  The GetTableNames function works fine.  If I go into SQL*Plus and query, I see the appropriate data

```
select count(*) from EGR.ACCOUNTS;
```

So I know my SCHEMA.TABLENAME is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it to the `items` property of the stringlist which is of type `TStrings`.

`procedure GetFieldNames(const TableName: string; List: TStrings);`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help (changing S1 from TStringlist to TStrings).  The docs shows using TListbox.Items as an example per your comment.  That does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

To get hand on a data field by its name, you shall use this code:

```
var
    FieldEgrAccount : TField;
begin
    FieldEgrAccount := AdoQuery1.FieldByName('SomeFieldName');
    Memo1.Lines.Add(FieldEgrAccount.AsString);
end;
```

If you really need to have all field names, use this code:

```
var
    Names : TStringList;
begin
    Names := TStringList.Create;
    try
        AdoQuery1.GetFieldNames(Names);
        // Do something with the field names

    finally
        Names.Free;
    end;
end;
```

It is much faster to use one TField per field, get it once and reuse it as many times as needed (Make the variable fields of the form or datamodule class). FieldByName is relatively costly because it has to scan the list of field names.

Comment: While I am assuming this will probably work for a given query, the problem I am running into is related to TADOConnection.GetFieldNames.  It takes 2 parameters, the name of the table whose fields I want to view, and the TStrings where to put the list of fields.  While I can work around the issue with code like you have shown, I am learning ADO, and trying to determine WHY something that should be working is not.

Comment: TADOConnection.GetFieldNames seems linked to the TAdoTable component. Maybe you should first link a TAdoTable with the TAdoConnection and only then request the field names for that table. Just guessing.